# (2010) access to flag for "show markup"?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-2010, word-2010

I was trying to create a keyboard shortcut for the "display for review" command in Review tab>tracking. Ultimately I'd like to toggle between "final" and "final:show markup" views without using an alt-sequence or macro.

I've found commands DisplayFinalDoc and DisplayOriginalDoc, but neither command controls the "show markup" flag (or however this is handled in Word). The DisplayForReview command doesn't seem to affect anything.

Is there a way to directly access and change the "show markup" flag in Word 2010?

```
Sub ShowMarkupToggle()
'
' ShowMarkupToggle Macro
    With ActiveWindow.View
        If .ShowRevisionsAndComments = True Then
            .ShowRevisionsAndComments = False
            .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewFinal
        Else
            .ShowRevisionsAndComments = True
            .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewFinal
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The code works, but I'm curious as to if there is a way to access the .ShowRevisionsAndCommens property without needing to save a macro-enabled doc, as this screws up my workflow (I'm a writer by trade, not a coder!)

Comment: can you post some code you already have?

Comment: @Voles I added the code I'm using which works for me, but I'm hoping to bypass using macros if it's possible. Maybe I should be asking a different question, like: how can I access and change the .ShowRevisionsAndComments property in my docs without needing to save as a macro-enabled filetype?

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> Ultimately I'd like to toggle between "final" and "final:show markup" views without using an alt-sequence or macro.

You can't, you have to use a macro.  But your working document (where you do your writing) does not have to be a docm document.  Here's how:

1. Save your macro `ShowMarkupToggle` in a docm document named
   "My_Macros.docm".
2. Assign a shortcut to your macro in the "My_Macros.docm" document.
3. Move "My_Macros.docm" to the following folder:
   `C:\Users\yru\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP`.

Now, when you open any Word document (docx), your macro `ShowMarkupToggle` and the associated shortcut will be available for use.

By the way, I have the same macro assigned to shortcut ALT+T, and here's how I do toggling:

```
' Toggle Track Changes FinalShowingMarkup and Final states.
' Shortcut: ALT+T

Sub Alt_T_TC_Toggle()
    With ActiveWindow.View
        .ShowRevisionsAndComments = Not .ShowRevisionsAndComments
        .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewFinal
    End With
End Sub
```

A note: When you need to modify your macro for any reason, you need to move the document out of the folder specified above, because of security reasons.  When you are done with the modifications, move it back in.

(This is one macro that has been a huge timesaver for me, well worth the time I spent crafting it.)